# Why doesn't SFINAE select the const-reference-taking overload?

Tags: c++, c++14

In this code

```
struct A {int commmon; int rare;};
struct B {int commmon;};

struct L {
    template<class T>
    int f(const T& t) {return t.commmon;}
    template<class T>
    int f(T& t) {return t.rare;}
};

void func() {
    A a; B b; L l;

    l.f(a);
    l.f(B{});
    l.f(b);
}
```

the final lines gives me the error

```
In instantiation of ‘int L::f(T&) [with T = B]’:
error: ‘struct B’ has no member named ‘rare’
```

But according to my understanding of SFINAE, the second overload should be ignored because of the substitution failure in the body. Why doesn't this happen?

**EDIT:** If I change the return type of the second overload to `decltype(T::rare)`, it does what I want. So where does my SF need to happen to be NAE?

Comment: read the explanation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae In short: The SF has to be in the function declaration, not in the body.

Comment: @mch Wow, that explanation is much better than Wikipedia's.

Comment: You might use something like  `template<class T> auto f(T& t) -> decltype(t.rare)  {return t.rare;}` to enable SFINAE for your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least verbose way to fix that is to use an `auto` return type with a trailing return type on the more constraint overload:

```
struct L {
    template <class T>
        auto f(const T& t) {return t.commmon;}
    template <class T>
       auto f(T& t) -> decltype(t.rare) {return t.rare;}
};
```

The advantage of this approach is that the constraint is specified at a point where the compiler has already seen the function argument, allowing for a shorter notation than `std::enable_if` clauses in the declaration of template parameters:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct L {
   template <class T>
       int f(const T& t) {return t.commmon;}
   template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, A>, int> = 0>
       int f(T& t) { return t.rare;}
};
```

Note further that the more constrained function won't be called when passing an rvalue argument. You might want to fix that by changing the function signatures to

```
template<class T /*, ... */>
    int f(T&& t) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE does not apply to function bodies [[temp.deduct/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#8):

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the **function type, its template parameter types, and its explicit-specifier** can result in a deduction failure.

Answer (score 0):

Template arguments are deduced *before* the function actually is instantiated. At the time the implementation is evaluated, the deduction has already occurred. So all that's relevant for deduction is the function *signature*, and from the existing ones, the non-const variant is fine to select.

If you want to apply get SFINAE applied depending on members existing, you have to do this within the function signature already. [lubgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9593596/lubgr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376165/1312382) reflects this nicely: The return type is `decltype(t.rare)`; if T does not provide a `rare` member, the return type cannot be deduced and thus the overload is not considered during resolution.

Found two other answers dealing with the matter you might be interested in: [C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13787502/1312382), [compatible to pre-C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039660/1312382)